# Magento 2: Preload shipping estimation without filling up shipping address details

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods, knockout

In checkout cart summary, is there a way to preload the shipping estimation without filling up the detail and choosing the shipping method? so when we first load it will show subtotal, shipping rate, and Order total

Comment: You can auto select shipping method..

Comment: how to do that @Pawan ?

Comment: You can use free module from BSS https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-preselect-shipping-payment-extension.html